# Writing Loops with multiplication C#

Tags: c#, loops

I am having an issue with trying to write a loop that requires me to multiply. What I am trying to do is write a loop that outputs:

```
i*3 for i = 10 t i = 4000
```

I tried using a counter method but it seems I am doing something wrong so i tried to fix it an did this

```
int i = 10;
        for (i = 10; i < 4000; ) 
        {
        int r = i * 3;
        Console.WriteLine(r);
```

but the number 30 goes into an infinite loop. Any help is appreciated, I am trying to do this for fun so I am self learning. Thanks again!

Comment: Based on your comments, after you've printed `r`, you need to replace `i` with the value you're calculating for `r`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there (based on your comments)

```
int i = 10;
while (i < 4000) 
{
    int r = i * 3;
    Console.WriteLine(r);
    i = r;
}
```

If it has to be a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 10; i < 4000; ) 
{
    int r = i * 3;
    Console.WriteLine(r);
    i = r;
}
```

Comment: I was just about to try the While statement you got it for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You need an `i++`

```
 for (i = 10; i < 4000; i++)
```

currently you have a for loop, but `i` never changes

if you want your new requirement :-

```
var r = 10;
while(r < 4000)
{
   r = r * 3;
   Console.Writeline(r);
}
```

or

```
for (var r = 30; r < 4000; r = r * 3)
{
     Console.WriteLine(r);
}
```

Comment: Alright I ended up writing this  for (i = 10; i <= 4000; i++) but what happens is I ended up starting at 11106 - 1200. What I am trying to do is have it multiply from 10 x' 3 then 11 x's 3 and so on until I hit 4000.

Comment: and does it do what you want now?

Comment: I re-edited my last response, but it seems to be going up by multiples of three when it should be multiplying by 3.

Comment: what are you expecting the output to be?  if i starts at 10, then you get 30 33 36  etc... what are you expecting?

Comment: I think @User is expecting 30, 90, 270, etc... for all values under 4000. Correct?

Comment: Does it have to be a `for` loop? A `while` or a `do-while` loop would be a better solution.

Comment: It worked for me any loop would've worked but the while make more sense to me.

Comment: the while or for in my answer are both pretty legit ways of doing it

Comment: okay the For loop seems to be a quicker way of doing it. I understand this so much better.

Comment: you can make it shorter by replacing r=r*3  as r*=3   I left it expanded since its not as obvious for someone who's new to the language

Comment: I greatly appreciate that, that may help in the future.

Answer (score 0):

is result of loop sum of you multiplication? you have two problems

1. you're not incrimenting i `for (i = 10; i < 4000; i++)`
2. you're not adding to r, declare it outside of loop, then `r += i * 3;`

Comment: did  he say he wanted r to accumulate all the multiplications?

Comment: not uncommon for people to store the result of a calculation in a variable, then print/store it.   Makes it a bit easier in the debugger if you want a break point and see what it evaluates to

Answer (score 0):

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 10; i < 4000; i = i*3 )
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

E.g.
Array : { 3, 30, 7, 8 })
Top 3 elements of this array is : 30 , 8 ,7
Output : 30 * 8 * 7 =  1680

Array : { 3, 30, 7, 8, -10, -20 })
Top 3 elements of this array is : 30 , 8 ,7
Output : 30 * 8 * 7 =  1680

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(MaxProduct(new int[] { 7,8,9,10,11,12,13}, 5));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static int MaxProduct(int[] arr, int no)
    {
        int prev = 0;
        int count = 1;
       // if (no >= 1)
        {
            Array.Sort(arr);
            Array.Reverse(arr);

            for (int i = 0; i < no-1 ; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    prev = arr[i] * arr[i + 1];
                }
                else
                {
                    prev = prev * arr[count];
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        return prev;
    }
```